# Getting a TypeError error when i return a variable of a Python program

Tags: python, flask, typeerror

I am trying to put contents of web form to python script. I have used below code, when i hit submit, i must see the output on the webpage. Basically Hello,  (taken from web page as input). I encounter a type error.

```
#!/bin/python

import os

from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def my_form():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['text']
    cmd = "sh relay.sh " + text
    rep = os.system(cmd)
    return rep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am getting the following error when i run this. I am basically trying to pass some info from a webpage (text box). I just entered 'Damnnn' to check output.

```
Hello, Damnnn
10.x.x.x - - [19/Jan/2017 0227:11:51] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 911, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Pardon me, I am new to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you are returning is a int, try to cast to string like this.

```
return str(rep)
```

Comment: Do you want to excecute that command and retrieve the output?  https://www.journaldev.com/16140/python-system-command-os-subprocess-call